"auto" keyword not working properly in Eclipse during live code analysis?
I'm using Eclipse with the MinGW compiler. I have the following code snippet, which results in the error "Method 'push_back' could not be resolved", but surprisingly the code works. More surprisingly I don't get the error for the 'sp' pointer accessing class members. But I get the error again when using range based for-loops as shown with p_elem
auto sp = std::make_shared<ClassType>();

auto spv1 = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassType>>>();

spv1->push_back(sp); // Method 'push_back' could not be resolved
sp->get_data(); // no error despite use of 'auto'

for (const auto &p_elem : *spv1) 
    p_elem->get_data() // Method 'get_data' could not be resolved

If i explicitly define the types like this (except for 'sp'), I don't get any error.
auto sp = std::make_shared<ClassType>();

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassType>>> spv2 = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassType>>>();

spv2->push_back(sp); // no error
sp->get_data(); // no error

for (const std::shared_ptr<ClassType> &p_elem : *spv2) 
    p_elem->get_data() // no error

There seems to be a problem with the auto keyword and live code analysis (as the code compiles error free and runs correctly despite unresolved messages). I've tried this solution Multiple "could not be resolved" problems using Eclipse with minGW

Go to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc. -> Providers -> CDT GCC built-in compiler settings, deactivate Use global provider shared between projects and add the command line argument -std=c++11.

and rebuild the index but it didn't work.
What settings in Eclipse am I missing? And why does the error only occur in the more complex statement with vector while both statements use the make_shared function.
